# Determine if a raster layer exists in a file geodatabase

Tags: arcpy, raster, layers, file-geodatabase, feature-class

I'm trying to determine if a layer file already exists in a given file geodatabase using arcpy.Exists.

I wrote a code that works without problems for Feature layers, however it doesn't work for Raster layers.

To figure out where the problem is, in my code I create a new empty gdb and check if a layer baseName exists in the new gdb. For Feature layers it returns False, as one would expect, given that the gdb is empty. However it returns True for the raster layers. The code is exactly the same except one looks at Feature layers and the other at Raster layers. Where is my mistake?

Here is the code for Feature layers, returning False for all Feature layers:

```
import arcpy

 #sets the processing target to the current aprx

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:/Test.aprx")

# Execute CreateFileGDB
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management("C:/empty.gdb")


m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
#loop to gather source paths of each layer in current aprx and export each to the out directory defined above

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:/empty.gdb"    
for lyr in m.listLayers():
#checks that each layer has a datasource attribute
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE") and lyr.isFeatureLayer is True:

       #grabs the layer's datasource
        ds = lyr.dataSource
        # Describe the feature class
        desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
        #grabs the layer's name from the table of contents
        nm = desc.baseName
        print(arcpy.Exists(nm))
```

Here is the code for Raster layers, returning True for all Raster layers:

```
import arcpy

 #sets the processing target to the current aprx

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:/Test.aprx")

# Execute CreateFileGDB
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management("C:/empty.gdb")


m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
#loop to gather source paths of each layer in current aprx and export each to the out directory defined above

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:/empty.gdb"    
for lyr in m.listLayers():
#checks that each layer has a datasource attribute
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE") and lyr.isRasterLayer is True:

       #grabs the layer's datasource
        ds = lyr.dataSource
        # Describe the feature class
        desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
        #grabs the layer's name from the table of contents
        nm = desc.baseName
        print(arcpy.Exists(nm))
```

Comment: [Layers](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) does not exist in file geodatabases: "Returns a Python list of Layer objects that exist within a map document (.mxd), a data frame within a map document, or layers within a layer (.lyr) file.". You want to check if the source of all layers in your map document are a specific file geodatabase?

Comment: @BERA, you're right, I didn't express myself correctly.
What my code does is identify the source file of a layer and check if the basename of that source exists within the new geodatabase. This assumes that the basename in the source geodatabase is the same as in the new geodatabase.
But I still don't understand why arcpy.Exists is working for Feature layers, but not for Raster layers.